# 3D software with easy human character personalization

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I was thinking in a 3D software with some human model with these features:

- Change joints positions (to create any posture easily)
- Change gender
- Change skeleton (to make it taller, bigger hands, etc)
- Change muscles and fat (to define how fit is)
- Change face (bigger nose, mouth, ears, etc)
- Change facial expressions
- Change hair (with different types and predesigned hairstyles)

Is there anything like on the market?

I've found "MakeHuman" and "ManuelBastioniLab for Blender" are a bit similar, but from what I've seen it does not work on the same way, it has many presents to change the body and face, but I think is better something with anatomic level to have more control.
PowerPose for Daz3D Genesis 8 seems to be a good option for facial expressions, but is lacking all the others.

Comment: I haven't used it in a few years, but Poser used to be great for most if not all of the things you listed. https://my.smithmicro.com/poser-3d-animation-software.html?

Comment: Not that I want to push any particular product, but there is [Adobe Fuse CC](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/fuse.html). If you already have a CC subscription, you already have access to it. If not, then it might be a bit expensive.

Comment: Adobe Fuse, Poser, Daz 3D all fit the bill, as does Make Human. There *used* to be a free online tool managed by Autodesk, but I think that one was sunsetted. All these "generate a person" tools will only get you so far - you will have a somewhat generic person with some specific traits, and if you want to tune expressions, shapes of noses and lips, brow formation, cheekbone height and angle and so on, you'll need both a real 3D DCC (Digital Content Creation) app (Blender, Modo, Maya, 3DS, C4D, Z-brush, Mudbox) and either digital sculpting knowledge/skills or 3D generalist skills.

Comment: I've seen one of the best are Daz3D, iClone and maybe Poser. But from what I've seen they don't work on the anatomic level, I mean is not possible to change only the femur, or biceps, is more like a plastic body not an anatomic body.